# To prove $r_2$ is a uniformly at random value in $Z_n$, where $r_2=r_1 . m$

Tags: cryptanalysis, randomness, one-time-pad

$m$ is arbitrary value in $Z_n$, where n is RSA modulo. Then we do: $r_2=r_1 . m (modn)$, where $r_1$ is a random value such that $r_1\in Z^*_n$.

** Question(1): is  $r_2$ a uniformly at random value in $Z_n$?

**Question(2): Would this be secure: $r_2=r_1 . m (modn)$ (where $m\in Z_n$ and $r_1\in Z^*_n$ )?

Comment: Hint: What is the condition making $f: r_1\to f(r_1)=r_2=r_1\cdot m\bmod n$ a bijection over $Z^*_n$? $\;$ And how likely is that condition assuming $m$ is defined without knowledge allowing the factorization of $n$?

Comment: @fgrieu Got a bit confused

Comment: I hope _Got_ is in the past tense. $\;$ My hint allows an easy proof. Find it, and you'll be able to solve many similar exercises.

Comment: @fgrieu many thanks for your "questions".But I think I did not ask a question to get to more questions. Many thanks by the way.

Comment: Rephrased without a question mark: $\;$ Show that if $m$ has a multiplicative inverse in $Z^*_n$, then $f: r_1\to f(r_1)=r_2=r_1\cdot m\bmod n$ is an [injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Injective_function) from $Z^*_n$ to itself. $\;$ Show that if an $m$ chosen in $Z^*_n$ without knowledge allowing the factorization of $n$ had sizable odds of having no multiplicative inverse, it would be easy to factor $n$. $\;$ Conclude about what we can safely assume about $f$ (noticing $Z^*_n$ is a finite set); then about what that implies for $r_2$ if $r_1$ is uniformly random.

Comment: @fgrieu I did a bit modification to the main question, but the whole story is the same as before.

Comment: @user153465: the answer to question 1 is "no"; if $m$ is an arbitrary value, consider the case that $m=0$; obviously in that case, $r_2$ is not a uniform random value.  For the answer to question 1 to be "yes", we need to put restrictions on the distribution $m$ is chosen from (specifically, that probabilities that $m$ is a multiple of $p$, $q$ and $pq$ must be $1/p$, $1/q$ and $1/pq$)

Comment: @user153465: indeed, to answer Question 1 by the affirmative, we need to replace _arbitrary value in_ $Z_n$ with _random in_ $Z_n$ (as Poncho did), or _chosen in_ $Z^*_n$ _without knowledge of the factorization of_ $n$ (as I did). $\;$ Question 2 as currently worded is not answerable by yes or no until both _this_ and _secure_ are better defined.

Comment: @fgrieu $m$ is a message, so how it could be defined to be: $m \in Z^*_n$ ? To be more clear is there any encoding allows us to do that? So what I realized from your useful answers, is that if I could define $m \in Z^*_n$ the answer to the second question would be yes.

Comment: @poncho Would it affect the security if $m<p,q$? So we could pick very large $p,q$.

Comment: The answer to that would depend on what you mean by 'security'.  You may find it helpful to write down exactly what you mean by that; what security properties are you expecting?

Comment: @poncho I have a list of values. I want to outsource it to the server, but I don't want to use any public/ private key encryption. So I want to multiply each value by a distinct random value, then send the list to the server. I don't want the server to know anything about the list elements. I need to remove these randomness from the list. So I can download this and remove these randomness. (One may ask why don't you use secret key encryption, and the answer is I need to do computation while they are at the server.

Comment: By computation while they are at the server, you mean the RSA public or private operations?  If so, well, what you're doing is known as RSA Blinding; it's a well known technique to allow someone to do the RSA operations without leaking what they're operating on.  It's known to be safe.

Comment: @poncho In fact the computation is on encrypted value. For instance $E_{cn}(r_1^{-1}.C)$, where $E_{cn}$ denotes additive homomorphic. So I can remove $r_1$,then multiply by $C$ securely. However this encryption can be done by another client, who knows $r^{-1}_1$ (Sorry if it's vague). But my concern is whether outsourcing $r_2=r_1 .m$ is secure against this server, where I cannot define $m$ such that $m\in Z^*_n$ but I can let it be $m\in Z_n$.  Last question: If I pick $Z_p$ instead of $Z_n$ would everything be sorted?

Comment: To conclude if we pick $r_1$ uniformly at random in $Z_n$ such that $gcd(r_1,n)=1$ then $r_2$ is uniformly at random in $Z_n$.  Please correct me if I'm wrong.